# The difference between $d\mu(\omega)$ and $\mu(d\omega)$

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be measure space and $f:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ be a integrable function.

What is the difference between the following two formulas :

$$
(1) \int_{\Omega} f(\omega)d\mu(\omega) 
\qquad 
(2) \int_{\Omega} f(\omega)\mu(d\omega) 
$$

are the two formulas identical?

Comment: Yes, they are the same thing.  Some text books use the one notation, some the other, and some (like Bogachev's _Measure Theory_, chap 2) use both.

Comment: $df(x) = f'(x)dx$ works when $f$ is a function or a distribution whereas $\mu(dx)$ strongly suggests that $\mu$ is a measure. When $\mu$ is a Borel measure on $\Bbb{R}$ then $\mu(A)=\int_A g(x)dx$ for some distribution $g$ so $\mu(dx)= g(x)dx$